# RequestBody annotation doesn't work in Liferay 7 Spring MVC Portlet

Tags: ajax, spring, liferay-7

I am trying to use @RequestBody Spring annotation inside a Controller which is part of a Spring MVC Portlet in Liferay 7.2

I made sure that the json is correct and the call, the client side is built correctly.
The json is getting nicely printed in the console log, and I was expecting that the @RequestBody annotation would get the json and do the "magic" and populate the SearchForm object.

The SearchForm object it is a Pojo with one field and I followed up a tutorial row by row and made sure that everything it is matching correctly.

This is my controller and my ajax call

```
@ResourceMapping(value = "search")
public void search(@RequestBody SearchForm search, Errors errors) {
    System.out.println("wow");
    if (search != null) {
        System.out.println(search.getUsername());
    } else {
        System.out.println("search obj was null");
    }
}


<script>

    $.ajax({
        url: "${search}" ,
        type: 'POST',
        datatype:'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
 });
```

I was expecting that SearchForm object would be populated and print something in the log.
But I am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: @RequestBody not supported
```

I am wondering if this issue is caused by an incompatibility between Liferay and requestBody, if yes how can I use this annotation in Liferay

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you need post in backend, it should be `@RequestMapping(value = "search", method=RequestMethod.POST)`

Comment: In Spring MVC Portlets in Liferay 7 I can see that I can not use multiple time @ResourceMapping, What I am trying to achieve is to pass a json object from FE to BE